# python CGI email dynamic output as a text file attachment

Tags: python, email, text, cgi, attachment

I am trying to send an email using python that has the standard To From, body, etc. However this is where my question comes in. My python script takes information in a string and manipulates it(adds,removes, formats, etc) I am trying to take this output and send it as an attachment on-the-fly. I know I can dump the output to a text file and then attach it to the email. However, due to the security of this CGI script I cannot write to the CGI directory. Is there a way to dynamically create a textfile object and send it as an attachment?

Using Python SMTP module.

I cannot create a traditional static text file due to permissions. I would like to see if Python is able to create a text file upon execution that i can populate with data and then attach to the email smtp module.

Comment: What are you using to send the mail? Python's smtp module?

Answer (score 1):

The last example on [this page](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html) shows how to create and send multi-part MIME message that contains text and HTML parts using the `smtplib` and`email` modules. It should be easily adaptable to your need to send a message as an attachment (ideally the attachment should have a content-type of `message/rfc822`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using smtplib and email.mime.multipart modules? the attach() method of the MIMEMultipart class accepts chunk of data to be attached, not a file.

Comment: Hmm, do you have any examples?

Comment: This seems to be the direction I want to go in. Seeing I am not able to attach a static file due to permissions. Is there a way to python can create a textfile "object" on execution that is attached to the email?